# c++ Deleting duplicated Names in array

Tags: c++, arrays

EDIT: Thank you so much everyone, songyuanyao Answered my question, and you guys did lol but i didnt know some codes u put and im sure soon i will learn them :) thanks again.

i really have a question about removing duplicated Names in a string, note that im fairly new to c++, anyways i'll get to the point.
what im trying to do is removing duplicated names in an array, the code below is working fine but here's what im facing.
For example i entered 4 names: (Hana, Alex, Hana, Alex) the results that i want to get is just : ( Hana and Alex) while the other 2 names should be removed yet what im getting is ( Hana , Alex, Alex).
im really confused about what should i do to fix this and i want it to check every name in the list, Thanks in advance :).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string nurse[4];
int i, n=3, j, k, num;
int main()
{
cout << "Please Enter names to add to the list --->";
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    cin >> nurse[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = i + 1; j < n;)
        if (nurse[j] == nurse[i])
        {
            for (k = j; k < n; k++)
            {
                nurse[k] = nurse[k + 1];

            }
            n--;
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
        }
}
cout << "Printing list after removing duplicated names" << endl;
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    cout << " "<<nurse[i] << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)!

Comment: You should also post what problems you face. It is easier to look for a solution then. For example, is your problem that the program does not complete execution here? Maybe because you missed a j++ in for (j = i + 1; j < n;)

Comment: `std::sort` and then `std::unique`. Or reinvent them.

Comment: xD im sorry its not really a problem its just why i cant shift those names, plus i dont know those commands im fairly knew to c++

Comment: Your code is all good, it's `<=` in the printing and reading loops that result in error ([demo](http://ideone.com/GhPur4)).

Comment: so u suggest i put only <?

Comment: We suggest you learn that array indexing is 0-based and the latest usable index is `size - 1`, as this is an extremely important thing to know and can cause endless unpredictable horror if not enforced. Had you indexed using `.at(index)`, the program would throw an exception at the last iteration of your `print` loop. `.at()` can be a performance sink but is invaluable during development/debugging and for a new programmer. For extra points, use a Standard Library implementation that has a 'debug mode' where you use normal `[]` and apply bounds-checking during the debugging phase, but not after

Comment: Yup will do that, Ty mate

Comment: np. and yes. using `< size` is the usual quick way to do this! but bounds-checking is worth trying, at least during the development phase, again because indexing outwith bounds accesses other memory, causing UB.

Comment: xDD yeah im just kinda new so a noob here lol :)

Comment: When your print loop was accessing 1-past-the-end (which I assume it isn't anymore!), what happened? Since you're accessing out-of-bounds memory, the program is allowed to do anything! (Undefined Behaviour)

Comment: uhm after editing the code it worked fine no matter how many duplicated names i enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You condition in `for` is one less than the count of the elements, so the last element won't be checked at all.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
                   ~
{
    for (j = i + 1; j <= n;)
                       ~
        if (nurse[j] == nurse[i])
        {
            for (k = j; k <= n; k++)
                           ~
            {
                nurse[k] = nurse[k + 1];

            }
            n--;
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
        }
}
```

Comment: ooo Ty for the answer mate

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// ...

vector<string> nurses;
nurses.push_back("Hana");
nurses.push_back("Alex");
nurses.push_back("Hana");
nurses.push_back("Alex");
sort(nurses.begin(), nurses.end());
const vector<string>::iterator it = unique(nurses.begin(), nurses.end());
nurses.erase(it, nurses.end());
```

Comment: xD tbh they all right answers but i just dont know the codes yet so

Comment: This answer is elegant in its way, but it should be noted that the complexity is n log(n), whereas it can be done with (expected) linear time.

Comment: I think the accepted answer is the most appropriate one because it explains why the student's code didn't work.

Comment: @V-R For the record, I think your answer is fine. In fact, there can be several fine answers to a question. Different approaches are good.

Comment: @Ami, thanks, and personally I liked your answer the most because it teaches me modern C++. So yeah, win/win

Comment: I'm upvoting this for your use of `unique` (a less-often used algorithm).

Answer (score 3):

Say you start with

```
vector<string> v{"alex", "emma", "alex"};
```

Define an [`unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) with these items:

```
unordered_set<string> h;
```

Now use the [`erase`-`remove` idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) using

```
[&h](const string &s){return !h.insert(s).second;};
```

This will do the job in (expected) linear time.

---

Full example:

```
#include <string>                                                                                                                                                                                            
#include<vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    vector<string> v{"alex", "emma", "alex"};
    unordered_set<string> h;

    auto r = [&h](const string &s){return !h.insert(s).second;};

    v.erase(remove_if(begin(v), end(v), r), end(v));
}
```

Comment: Ty mate! my question is answered xD

Answer (score 1):

You are effectively not **removing** names from your array. You are just shifting them in case same name comes!

You could actually use a `std::set` which will automatically do this for you!

```
std::set< std::string > nurses;
std::string nurse;
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    std::cin >> nurse;
    nurses.insert( nurse );
}
```

Do not forget to include `<set>` in your code.

Comment: i would really love to use that command but i dont know it lol, maybe soon the professor will explain it

Comment: So it is a *homework* question? Use a debugger and see what's going wrong with your code!

Comment: no its not a homework question im doing it because it came in the pop quiz and i solved it and then he said there is another way u can do it, so im trying to figure it out xD

Comment: Using STL containers like `std::set` is another way.